# Stored procedure isn't returning the related table data

Tags: mysql, laravel, stored-procedures

I hope some one can help me with a stored procedure which loops through all tenants and get properties along with images. The property and images table have a polymorphic relationship through imageables table. Here are the simplified tables;

```
properties
----------
id
title
location


images
--------
id
url


imageables
----------
image_id -- references images table
imageable_id -- references id on properties table
imageable_type -- e.g. App\Property or App\Room
```

Following is the stored procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `getAllPropertiesWithImages`()
    DETERMINISTIC
    COMMENT 'test'
BEGIN
    DECLARE queryString TEXT DEFAULT '';
    DECLARE tenant_db_id VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT '';
    DECLARE done INTEGER DEFAULT 0;

    -- Cursor to fetch distinct tenant database IDs
    DECLARE tenant_cursor CURSOR FOR
        SELECT DISTINCT(table_schema)
        FROM information_schema.TABLES
        WHERE table_schema LIKE 'tenant%';

    -- Continue handler for cursor not found
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND
        SET done = 1;

    OPEN tenant_cursor;

    read_loop: LOOP
        FETCH tenant_cursor INTO tenant_db_id;

        IF done = 1 THEN
            LEAVE read_loop;
        END IF;

        IF queryString != '' THEN
            SET queryString = CONCAT(queryString, ' UNION ALL ');
        END IF;

        -- Append the SELECT query for each tenant's properties with image URLs as JSON
        SET queryString = CONCAT(
            queryString,
            ' SELECT
                p.id,
                p.title,
                p.published as is_live,
                JSON_ARRAYAGG(i.url) AS images
            FROM `', tenant_db_id, '`.properties AS p
            LEFT JOIN `', tenant_db_id, '`.imageables AS ia ON p.id = ia.imageable_id AND ia.imageable_type="App\\Property"
            LEFT JOIN `', tenant_db_id, '`.images AS i ON ia.image_id = i.id AND i.deleted_at IS NULL
        
            WHERE p.deleted_at IS NULL
            GROUP BY p.id'
        );
    END LOOP;

    CLOSE tenant_cursor;

    SET @qStr = CONCAT('CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW allPropertiesWithImagesView AS ', queryString);

    PREPARE stmt FROM @qStr;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

    SET @qStr = NULL;

END
```

The problem is that when i run the procedure, it gives me `[null]` in images column for the properties. However, running the query on the tenant database gives me correct results. Can some one help to identify the issue as what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Leaving an answer for any body that would come across the same problem in the future. As I am checking `imageable_type` to be `App\Property`. I needed to do as follow;

```
 imageable_type="App\\\\property"
```

Here is the explanation as why,

> In MySQL, backslashes are escape characters, and when you want to
> include a literal backslash in a string, you need to escape it by
> using double backslashes (\)

. Since imageable_type is a string value, and I wanted it to be stored as App\Property, I needed to use `App\\\\Property` in the query.

Here's why:

The first backslash () is used to escape the second backslash, resulting in a single backslash in the string.
However, when working with MySQL, backslashes are also escape characters in strings, so I needed to escape the backslash again by using two backslashes (\).
Therefore, to store the value App\Property as a string in MySQL, I needed to use App\\Property in the query.
The quadruple backslashes (\\) in the query will be interpreted by MySQL as a single backslash (\), and the resulting value stored in the database will be App\Property